# C# how to cast object to runtime type?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I cast (or convert, if cast not possible or reasonable) an `object` into its runtime type? I can get `runtimeType` using reflection, but can't figure out how to get `List<string>` using `property.GetValue` - I know that I could explicitly do `as List<String>` but this is for a sort-of soft-code engine where the types are not known until runtime.

Any help is appreciated - thanks! (but looking for code solutions please, not "you shouldn't do it this way..." answers)

```
// trimmed-down example class
class Bus { public List<string> Passengers {get;set;} }

// create new instance of class
var obj = new Bus();

// get property value using reflection
var listPropertyName = "Passengers";
var property = GetType(obj).GetProperty($"{listPropertyName}");
var runtimeType = property.PropertyType;

// returns object, but I want List<string> instead 
// (or whatever it is; could be different types like T, List<T>, etc.)
var val = property.GetValue(obj);

// doesn't work (assigns null), expects compile-time type
var val = property.GetValue(obj) as runtimeType;
```

Comment: What would you need the `as` for? You'd need a variable of that type to do anything useful. But you don't know the type. On the other hand, using reflection, you can do anything on the member. You possibly confuse the type you see (`object`) from the `GetValue`'s signature with the actual type of the member which **is** `List<string>`.

Comment: I will know the type at runtime. I want to use `GetValue` to return the value in the proper type.

Comment: The only valid answer known to me (assuming you really understand how this works and the type is not fixed) is to use the CodeDOM compiler, i.e. create a dynamic code as string, put the actual member's type as the variable type, compile and invoke the newly compiled code.

Comment: `List<string>` is the compiler typename; it does not exist at runtime, as such. The CLR type system deals with objects of type `Type`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Shouldn't you firstly initialize Passengers property in the Bus obj?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you think `var` in C# is same as in JavaScript (which obviously not true) or same as `dynamic` (which is again not true)… Clarifying what you really want to do with the value of the property may help with  possible solutions (calling generic methods dynamically, `dynamic`, pure reflection, code gen,...)

Comment: Side note: I hope you understand that runtime type of `property` is not necessary the same as `runtimeType`...

Comment: I consider voting to close this as "unclear what you are asking". My first question "what do you need it for" still stands unanswered (not the downvoter though).

Comment: Why does it matter what I want it for? I don't want alternatives, I want to cast an `object` to a type that is known at run time instead of at compile time.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary: To learn if you not fall into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) category.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary "cast" in C# is usually used to refer to compile type concept - since obviously you can't use run-time type at compile time you probably use "cast" in some other meaning - it is very unclear what that meaning is. Showing what you want to achieve is a way to clarify what you are saying, not the only way... (So far there has been offered multiple suggestions on what you may be doing but it does not look like any of them align with your goal... )

Comment: I understand the initial confusion this can create. It's just a hump to get over, like getting used to the unfamiliar grammar of a foreign language. It seems unhelpful when someone tells you not to do what you're trying to do, but in this case it's the right answer. The compiler is like a parent who is always right. We fight with it for a while and try to figure out how to work around it. Then we learn that everything it tells us is for our own good. Then we listen to it and want it to tell us more.

Comment: You can invoke the cast operator via Reflection, but that usually doesn’t do any good if you can’t declare a variable of the type being cast. Since variables are declared at compile time, this isn’t going to do you much good. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Unless this is a duplicate of something - which is likely - I find the question valuable because this is something many of us run into. The constraints of the compiler are beneficial, but at some point we don't see why that is. If we could stop the compiler from telling us what to do then the logical conclusion would be just declaring everything everywhere as `object`. Or switching to VB.NET.

Comment: @ScottHannen: or declaring everything as `dynamic`. Note however that you are projecting the OP's question to your own understanding of the context. The OP were not that kind to provide any meaningful explanation of what their primary concern is. This stops me from upvoting your answer.

Comment: The only real way we can do this,is when we know something about the type and cast it to an interface or base type, this gives us the ability to use a contract that has been pre-specified. or we need to inspect the type and branch into a place that knows how to deal with it, like a switch or something or method overload resolution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can't cast something to an unknown type specified at runtime. That would mean that within your code, you don't know what the object's properties or methods are unless you use even more reflection. In that case what would be the point of casting it?

---

Sometimes we deal with types that aren't known until runtime. But unless the type really doesn't matter at all, the object is useless unless we can cast it to some predetermined type that is specified in our code, not at runtime.

In this line of code:

```
var val = property.GetValue(obj);
```

the declared type of `val` is inferred by the compiler. That type is `object` because that's the type that `GetValue` returns. The actual type of the object could be `string`, `int`, `List<Foo>`, whatever. But you've got a variable `val` of type `object`.

If you *could* do this:

```
var val = property.GetValue(obj) as runtimeType;
```

Then what would the compile-time type of `val` be? How can it have any, since `runTimeType` is a runtime value? The object is useless unless you can call methods or inspect its properties. But you can't do that without knowing the type, unless you use more reflection. But if your're going to do that then there's no point in casting it.

Somewhere downstream from the code you've posted you'll presumably want to actually do something with the object that involves its methods or properties. That means knowing what type you *think* it is and casting it as that type. That would be a type specified in your code, not something determined at runtime.

For example:

```
var val = property.GetValue(obj); // I know this is a string
var myString = (string)val;
var findX = myString.IndexOf("X");
```

I think it's a `string` so I cast it as a `string`. (There could be additional checks in there.) Now that I've cast it, I've got a variable that's declared as type `string`, and I can use it as a string. (Unless it wasn't a `string` - then it will throw a runtime exception.)

That's the benefit of casting - it allows us to assign something to a strongly-typed variable with a type we specify and then use it accordingly. Casting to an unknown type wouldn't benefit us.

---

At the risk of adding confusion: Someone could say that generics represent types unspecified at runtime, but that's not exactly true. `List<T>` doesn't specify what `T` is, but if you create a `List<T>`, somehow, somewhere you're going to specify the type in your code. In the vast majority of normal scenarios we have to know something about the type of an object or else the object is useless to us.